# ASP.NET MVC - Validation logic - where to place?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm trying to determine where to place my "Validation Models".

My structure is at the moment:

**Web** (have reference to Business and Objects)

- Controllers
- Views
- CSS
- Scripts

**Business** (have reference to Data and Objects)

- Services

**Data** (have reference to Objects)

- Repositories and EF Context(Code First)

**Objects**

- POCOs (for EF)

Now is my question where to place validation things like a LogIn Model? Should the model be placed in my Web layer or Objects layer? - or should I even store validation models like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Models should be placed in your business layer. View models should be placed in your web layer because they are tied to a view. You should have a mapping between your models and view models (to facilitate this task you may use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)). Views receive view models from controllers. Validation is performed on those view models.

So:

**Web**

- Controllers
- Views
- Models (here you may place your view models)
- CSS
- Scripts

Comment: So if I have a LogIn Model - then I have to place a model in my Business named "LogInModel" which is without any validation attributes at all.. In the Web layer I then create a "ViewModel" which applys validation rules to the LogInModel?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that needs to be validated should go in your Business layer. Validation is a business concern that shouldn't be scattered across layers and shouldn't be tied to a specific application type (web, windows, service, etc).

If you expose your domain model to the application then you can also decorate your entities with validation attributes, but note that if your domain model changes then your application breaks.

Let's say you have an `AccountService` class in the Business layer, which has a `Login` method. `Login` accepts a `LoginInput` class and returns a `LoginResult` class:

```
public class LoginInput {

   [Required]
   public string Username { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Password { get; set; }
} 

public class LoginResult {
   public bool Success { get; internal set; }
   public string Error { get; internal set; }
}
```

Both of these classes can be used as ViewModels, so you don't need to create any ViewModel in the Web layer, and you certainly shouldn't put validation logic in them.